# Resolving compilation errors for c++20 code on Mac

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compilation, c++20

I am trying to setup my machine to be able to compile c++20 code. I have a simple example code

```
#include <concepts>                                                                                                                              
#include <iostream>                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                 
template<typename T>                                                                                                                             
requires std::integral<T>                                                                                                                        
auto gcd(T a, T b) {                                                                                                                             
  if(b == 0) return a;                                                                                                                           
  else return gcd(b, a%b);                                                                                                                       
}                                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                                 
int main() {                                                                                                                                     
  std::cout << "\n";                                                                                                                             
  std::cout << gcd(100,10) << "\n";                                                                                                              
}
```

which I am trying to compile on a MacOS (11.5.1/BigSur).

xcode version - Xcode 12.5.1
Build version 12E507

clang version - Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)

compilation command

```
g++ -std=c++20 myfile.cpp
```

I get the following error:

```
myfile.cpp:25:24: error: 'T' does not refer to a value
requires std::integral<T>
                       ^
myfile.cpp:24:19: note: declared here
template<typename T>
                  ^
myfile.cpp:25:15: error: no member named 'integral' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'internal'?
requires std::integral<T>
         ~~~~~^~~~~~~~
              internal
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/ios:960:1: note: 'internal' declared here
internal(ios_base& __str)
^
myfile.cpp:26:1: error: expected expression
auto gcd(T a, T b) {
^
3 errors generated
```

Need help with this.

Comment: According to Wandbox, your code fails with your errors under clang 11.1.0, but successfully compiles with clang 13.0.0. So I would guess that this falls under "C++20 support is spotty" (but I cannot confirm that specifically). Do you have any documentation stating that your version of the compiler *does* support `std::integral`?

Comment: no, i don't know if it does or not. If it is supporting c++20, does it imply it will have std::integral ?

Comment: C++20 support is incomplete on all major compilers.

Comment: @echelon Do you have documentation stating that your version of the compiler supports C++20, with no caveats or limitations? (I doubt it, because, as I wrote, C++20 support is spotty.) *That being said, yes, **if** your compiler (fully) supports C++20, then it will have `std::integral`. However, you compiler does not fully support C++20, so there is no conclusion to draw.*